# How to uncomment multiple lines on second pattern match using sed?

Tags: sed, pattern-matching, lines, multiple-instances

I am trying to use sed to uncomment a block of text in this config file. 
The code I came up with  uncomments 7 lines starting from and including the pattern match  on the first match but I need it to only work on the second match and skip the first match.

```
                 sed '/#location.~.*$/,+6s/#/ /' default.conf
```

---

> 

```
# proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
#
#location ~ \.php$ {
#    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
#}

# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
#
#location ~ \.php$ {                
#    root           html;
#    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
#    fastcgi_index  index.php;
#    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
#    include        fastcgi_params;
#}
# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
#
```

>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'x;/./{x;/#location/,+6s/#/ /;b};x;/#location/h' file
```

Use the hold space (HS) to store a flag and only act on the address range if the flag has been set.

Comment: This is magic! Thanks for teaching me a bit more about sed :)

Answer (score 1):

I would say, using shell script to change your codes is risky. many special case could make it fail.

I would call it "text transformation" instead.  it will remove the leading `#` from `#location ~ \.php$ {` line to first `#}` line.

**awk** onliner:

```
 awk '/^#location ~/{s=1}s{if($0~/^#}/)s=0;sub("#"," ")}1' file
```

see example: (file is your content)

```
kent$  awk '/^#location ~/{s=1}s{if($0~/^#}/)s=0;sub("#"," ")}1' file
# proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
#
 location ~ \.php$ {
     proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
 }

# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
#
 location ~ \.php$ {                
     root           html;
     fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
     fastcgi_index  index.php;
     fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
     include        fastcgi_params;
 }
# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
#
```

I hope the output above is what you need.

Comment: Thanks so much but I need the first match to be ignored and I dont have any experience with awk to play around and modifiy it

Answer (score 0):

With [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) (this is more suitable & easier than `sed` for this task):

```
awk -F# '
    /^#location/{l++}
    l<2 {print}
    l==2{print $2}
    l==2 && $2 ~ "}" {l=0;next}
' file.txt
```

Comment: thanks mate, I couldn't get this to work as is, I must have done something wrong. I appreciate your your help though.